# What is the problem with this init(coder:) function?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I don't get it guys.
I'm trying to create a 2D game and i'm stuck with a very basic issue.
Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

   let box: SKSpriteNode
   let hero: SKSpriteNode

   override init(size: CGSize){
     hero = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: size.width / 5, height: size.height / 5))
     box = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))

     super.init(size: size)
     self.addChild(box)
     self.addChild(hero)
 }


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Setting up the scene
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
```

Xcode indicates me the following error :"Property 'self.box' not initialized at super.init call" at the init (coder:) function.

Then i tried to replace it with:

```
required init?(coder a Decoder: NSCoder){
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented)
}
```

But guess what... when i launch the game it indicates me that i have a fatal error.
When i delete all initializers it tells me that i need initialisers.
Do you have any idea of how to do it?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: You do have to initialize `box` and `hero` also in `init(coder`. According to the rules every non-optional property must be initialized in **all** provided `init` methods.

Comment: Hi and thanks but  i don't want to initialize box and hero in init(coder:). Only in init(size:).

Comment: That's not possible with non-optional properties. A workaround could be to initialize the nodes with zero size. Or declare the properties as optional.

Comment: FYI, the fact that the app crashes with the `fatalError` approach proves that this initializer is being called, probably from a SpriteKit Scene file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `box` and `hero` are not optional, they must be initialized in all initializers.

You have done it for your custom initializer but you also need to do it for init with coder since that initializer can be invoked separate from your custom initializer.

Comment: OK man thank you for this answer, and it's the only way to do it i think.... And they say swift is simple...